# Font awesome icon not showing up after updating to 4.7

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I was using Font Awesome v4.6 and everything was working fine. I saw that 4.7 had newer icons so I tried updating to 4.7.

For my development, I am using a min.css file that is kept locally instead of using a CDN. I prefer to keep it this way.

To update to 4.7, I downloaded the new font-awesome.min.css file to replace 4.6. When I redeployed my server and reloaded the browser, the new icons are not showing, but the old icons are still showing just fine. I get no error in the logs. Any ideas?

Log:

```
GET /stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css 304 1.818 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

To update it, it's not enough to change only "min.css" file. You also need to update your fontawesome fonts. You can download from the link below and copy to directory where your min.css file call them.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts

Comment: I should clarify that I downloaded these as well, I got the zip file that contained the min.css file and these fonts

Comment: Do you have any link that i can control?

Comment: As in links you can see?

Comment: Yes, i would like check out.

Comment: Is there anything I should look for because this is a local development env

Comment: Actually i just want to check what I told you. If you can compile as prod and share with me, i'l try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a cache issue? Try to Ctrl+f5 the page on your browser. Also double check if you are using the right names for the icons, just in case.

Comment: I cleared the cache and double checked the names, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Cloudflare or a wordpress plugin that caches your website for you?

If you do this can be the cause.

Comment: No I am not using those

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.